# Can I bias this circuit to zero

Tags: single-supply-op-amp

[image: mic amp]

H i, I am new to this, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.
How can I bias this to zero, and is there a way to increase the dynamic range.
I will mbe using this as a sound trigger for an arduino based unit.

**edit:**
What I meant by Bias to zero was.  The output voltage ranges from 1.7 to 3.3, is it possible to have go from 0 to 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "bias to zero" to have zero DC output voltage, then just add a capacitor in series to the output of the opamp. If you need to increase the dynamic (input) range, you can either increase the supply voltage (also increases the output voltage range) or decrease the amplification.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the dynamic range (yet with more distortion), try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSZWxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>